# Executing the service command from c++ file

Tags: ros, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here curr_x and curr_y are the co-ordinates of the turtle

I'm getting these errors when I try to execute the following command.
I would like to teleport the turtle to absolute co-ordinates using the command

```
kv@kv:~/krssg$ rosservice call /turtle1/teleport_absolute "x: 0.25
y: 10.68
theta: -0.7854"
```

but I'm getting these errors when I to invoke this command from a c++ file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosservice", line 35, in <module>
    rosservice.rosservicemain()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 746, in rosservicemain
    _rosservice_cmd_call(argv)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 607, in _rosservice_cmd_call
    service_args.append(yaml.load(arg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 576, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 1, column 12:
    x: curr_x y: curr_y theta: 0.785
               ^
[ INFO] [1457543780.559175654]: 

[ INFO] [1457543780.559260990]: curr_x = 1.10889 curr_y = 9.98001
[ INFO] [1457543780.559285090]: [X][Y] = 0 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosservice", line 35, in <module>
    rosservice.rosservicemain()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 746, in rosservicemain
    _rosservice_cmd_call(argv)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 607, in _rosservice_cmd_call
    service_args.append(yaml.load(arg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 576, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 1, column 12:
    x: curr_x y: curr_y theta: 0.785
               ^
[ INFO] [1457543780.789418266]: 

[ INFO] [1457543780.789524534]: curr_x = 3.32667 curr_y = 7.76223
[ INFO] [1457543780.789578391]: [X][Y] = 1 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosservice", line 35, in <module>
    rosservice.rosservicemain()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 746, in rosservicemain
    _rosservice_cmd_call(argv)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 607, in _rosservice_cmd_call
    service_args.append(yaml.load(arg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 576, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 1, column 12:
    x: curr_x y: curr_y theta: 0.785
               ^
[ INFO] [1457543781.019473956]: 

[ INFO] [1457543781.019593133]: curr_x = 5.54444 curr_y = 5.54446
[ INFO] [1457543781.019635712]: [X][Y] = 2 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosservice", line 35, in <module>
    rosservice.rosservicemain()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 746, in rosservicemain
    _rosservice_cmd_call(argv)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 607, in _rosservice_cmd_call
    service_args.append(yaml.load(arg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 576, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 1, column 12:
    x: curr_x y: curr_y theta: 0.785
               ^
[ INFO] [1457543781.254734658]: 

[ INFO] [1457543781.254840801]: curr_x = 7.76222 curr_y = 3.32668
[ INFO] [1457543781.254876495]: [X][Y] = 3 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosservice", line 35, in <module>
    rosservice.rosservicemain()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 746, in rosservicemain
    _rosservice_cmd_call(argv)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 607, in _rosservice_cmd_call
    service_args.append(yaml.load(arg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 576, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 1, column 12:
    x: curr_x y: curr_y theta: 0.785
               ^
[ INFO] [1457543781.486443016]: 

[ INFO] [1457543781.486555978]: curr_x = 9.98 curr_y = 1.1089
[ INFO] [1457543781.486647417]: [X][Y] = 4 4
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228608/executing-the-service-command-from-c++-file/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this error message:

```
  yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 1, column 12:
    x: curr_x y: curr_y theta: 0.785
```

and the invoke call that you posted as a comment on Tully's answer:

```
 system("rosservice call /turtle1/teleport_absolute {\"x: curr_x y: curr_y theta: 0.785\"}");
```

The problem is that you need to substitute the strings *curr_x* and *curr_y* in the system call for the actual x and y values (double) that you want to send.

I bet this system call works well:

```
 system("rosservice call /turtle1/teleport_absolute {\"x: 0.25, y: 10.68, theta: 0.785\"}");
```

Anyway, if you are working in C++ this is not the proper way to call a ROS service. Better take a look at this tutorial: [Writing a Service Client Node](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B)#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1